# Swift Image retrieving from Parse sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform, uiimageview

I'm currently writing a social networking application in Swift. Inside my app I have feature that a user can send a message to the timeline with a image attached. I want to be able to retrieve the image and preview it using a UIImageView inside my timeline. I wrote the following function but I'm receiving a "unexpected found nil while unwrapping a Optional Value" error. I'm hoping somebody in the community can point out what I'm doing wrong.

```
func loadImages()
{
    var query = PFQuery(className: "imagesUploaded")
    query.orderByDescending("objectID")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:[AnyObject]!,error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let imagesobjects = objects as [PFObject]

            for object : PFObject in objects as [PFObject] {
                let image = object["filename"] as PFFile

                image.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        let finalimage = UIImage(data: imageData)
                        self.timelineImages.append(finalimage!)
                        self.timelineimage.image = finalimage?
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please include your function here, since this a programming related website, it's best you put your programming related code here

Comment: Please tell us which part you're getting the error on.

Comment: @TimothyWalters self.timelineimage.image = finalimage? is the part I'm getting a error on.

Comment: @DerekCacciotti how u have declared timelineimage and timelineImages ? please just show it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the error is happening around these lines:

```
self.timelineImages.append(finalimage!)
self.timelineimage.image = finalimage?
```

I would suggest it is either `finalimage`, `timelineImages` or `timelineimage`.

For finalimage I would use `if let`:

```
if let finalimage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
    self.timelineImages.append(finalimage)
    self.timelineimage.image = finalimage
}
```

This safely runs the code only if finalimage got a value.

If one of the others is coming back as nil you can solve that with `?`. thus your final code looks like this:

```
if let finalimage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
    self.timelineImages?.append(finalimage)
    self.timelineimage?.image = finalimage
}
```

Comment: I have a follow up question. Do you know how to display images in the timeline from the user that sent the image? I tried using a PFQuery but the images kept appearing in every cell even if the user did not send the image being. I can send you my source code for my timeline if you need it. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Create a new question, feel free to copy a link here as another comment once you've done so and I'll take a look at it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380170/creating-image-preview-using-swift-and-parse-sdk